# SQL JOIN filter for zero hits in Table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a Client table where some clients have a contract number.  We're doing a sanity check to make sure that our Services table has the service that goes with the contract.  So, I'm trying to construct a query where the contract field is non-empty, and there is NOT a proper service record to match that client.

Client

| id | Contract |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C01 |
| 2 | C02 |
| 3 | C03 |
| 4 |  |

Services (Where service 1 is the one we're looking for)

| id | ClientID | Service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 | 3 |
| 8 | 4 | 2 |
| 9 | 4 | 3 |

This should only display client 3 as having a contract without having the associated service it's supposed to have.

I have a query that shows me all records in the Services table for clients with contracts and the correct service code.  I can't figure out how to find records in the client table that are missing any examples of the record I want in the Services table.

This gets me records WITH the service

```
SELECT *
  JOIN[System].[dbo].[Services] ON Client.id = Services.ClientID AND Service = 1
  FROM [System].[dbo].[Client]
  WHERE NOT Contract = ''
```

I've tried JOINing the other direction, but it's still the same issue.

----- Edit -----
The reason I want to only display client 3 because that is the only one with a non-null Contract field where there does not exist in the Services table a record with ClientID=3 and Service=1.  There are Service=2 and Service=3, but not Service=1.  Clients 1 and 2 both have non-null Contract fields, but they also have a Services record where Service=1.  Client 4 has a null Contract field, so it should not have a Services record with Service=1.  (I'm not trying to display extraneous Services records with this query.  I can build that one on my own.)

Again, this is a sanity check.  If we have a contract number then we're supposed to have a record for the matching client with Service=1.  We think we have a few where that's not the case.  I'm trying to build a query that shows me the problem clients.

I guess in table form, the output for the query I'm trying to build would be:

| id | Contract | id | ClientID | Service |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | C03 | null | null | null |

I'm sure this has been answered elsewhere.  But, I can't think of search terms that will find that amongst the mountain of results I've gotten, thus far.  I guess generically, this is basically, "How do I query for situations with missing records."

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result. I.e. provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: *This should only display client 3* - why?

Comment: Your SQL is incorrect - *FROM* comes before *JOIN*

Comment: Sorry for the broken SQL.  I had several experiments going on, and I must have grabbed one that was being worked on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track. You needed a `LEFT JOIN` to the Services table matching on `ClientID` and the required `Service = 1`. You would then add a condition to the `WHERE` clause that checks for no match with an `IS NULL` test.

This can also be done using a `C.id NOT IN (subselect)` condition. A `NOT EXISTS()` condition can also be used.

Each of the following will identify clients with contracts, but lacking Service = 1.

```
SELECT C.*
FROM System.dbo.Client C
LEFT JOIN System.dbo.Services S
   ON S.ClientID = C.id
   AND S.Service = 1
WHERE C.Contract > ''
AND S.ClientID IS NULL
```

```
SELECT C.*
FROM System.dbo.Client C
WHERE C.Contract > ''
AND C.id NOT IN (
    SELECT S.ClientID
    FROM System.dbo.Services S
    WHERE S.Service = 1
)
```

```
SELECT C.*
FROM System.dbo.Client C
WHERE C.Contract > ''
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM System.dbo.Services S
    WHERE S.ClientID = C.id
    AND S.Service = 1
)
```

The execution plans for each of the above are nearly identical, so you can use the syntax that make the most sense to you.

All yield the following results:

| id | Contract |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | C03 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wN1_PJ8g) for a demo with indexes and query plan.